# Logging spring transactions with log4j2

Tags: java, spring, transactions, log4j2

At a project I am switching log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2
but I can't successfully migrate transaction logging, it doesn't log anything even if I switch to console appender.

Originally in log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.hibernate5=DEBUG, TRANSACTIONS
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${server.output.dir}/logs/transactions/transactions_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=100000000
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.TRANSACTIONS.Append=true
```

Now in log4j2.xml
Logger:

```
    <Logger name="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5" level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="Transactions"/>
    </Logger>
```

Appender:

```
<RollingFile name="Transactions" filePattern="${sys:server.output.dir}/logs/transactions/transactions_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="100000000" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy />
        </RollingFile>
```

I am sure the appender is correct because I use basically the same for other logging too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What dependencies do you use, are you using commons logging bridge? Similar thing happened to me, adding log4j-jcl helped.

Your dependencies should look like this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[As stated e.g. here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/log4j2-logging.html)